# Delete all service broker message types

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Currently I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types
```

to list service broker message types. However, how would I go about deleting all message types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example that drops all user message types in the current database, using the `model` database as a reference to exclude system message types.

Note the `DROP` will fail if contracts use the type. Contracts bound to the type and indirectly referencing SB objects (i.e. services) will need to be dropped first.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(N'DROP MESSAGE TYPE ' + QUOTENAME(current_db.name), ';')
FROM sys.service_message_types AS current_db
LEFT JOIN model.sys.service_message_types AS model_db ON
     model_db.message_type_id = current_db.message_type_id
WHERE model_db.message_type_id IS NULL;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```